# Web Scraping com python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Boa noite. Quero fazer um algortimo simples para tirar dados de um site (http://www.riooilgas.com.br/?_page=programacao&_menu=programacao).
Já fiz uma parte do código de bibliotecas:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.riooilgas.com.br/?_page=programacao&_menu=programacao")
res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib")
tags = res.findAll(text="Evento Paralelo - O&G Techweek")
print(res.tags)
```

Quero apenas as informações de dia, hora "Evento Paralelo - O&G Techweek
" e nome do evento. São 72 linhas, para imprimir em um excel algo simples.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente, os elementos que você procura não estão no código HTML do site, e sim são gerados dinamicamente via JavaScript depois que a página é carregada em um navegador. Como o BeautifulSoup não executa javascript, você não consegue extrair esses dados diretamente como começou em seu código.

Uma das opções para este tipo de site, é analisar o código javascript da página, descobrir o que ele faz, e "simular" isso com código python escrito manualmente. Essa solução geralmente é mais eficiente porém bem mais complexa de implementar.

No caso específico do site que você pediu, parece que os dados estão dentro do javascript, como pode ver aqui:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://assets.tuut.com.br/rog-pages/public/script-programacao-main.js?v=23')
>>> data = r.text
>>> data[30:100]
'po de Evento":"Congresso",Bloco:"",Categoria:"Credenciamento","Hor\xe1rio'
```

Como pode ver, é um formato similar ao json, mas não exatamente json. São definições de variáveis em javascript, com os dados. Usar o módulo `json` do python não funcionaria aqui porque o texto não é json válido, felizmente existe o módulo `demjson` que serve para extrair dados de formatos similares a json como esse. Usando `demjson`:

```
>>> d1 = data[data.find('['):data.find(']')+1]
>>> import demjson
>>> eventos = demjson.decode(d1)
```

Agora temos um objeto python (lista) contendo os eventos um a um em cada elemento:

```
>>> for evento in eventos:
...     print(evento['Nome do evento'], 'as', evento['Horário'], 'em', evento['Lugar'])
Credenciamento as 8:00 às 17:00 em Pavilhão 1
Cerimônia de Abertura as 9:30 às 11:00 em Pavilhão 5
SP 1: A nova geopolítica do petróleo e gás as 11:10 às 12:10 em Pavilhão 5
Os desafios e oportunidades do setor de Upstream num mundo em Transição Energética as 12:25 às 13:40 em Pavilhão 5
SE 01: 40 anos da Bacia de Campos: o que vem pela frente as 14:00 às 16:00 em Pavilhão 5
SE 02: Comércio irregular de combustíveis e seus impactos – programa Combustível Legal as 14:00 às 16:00 em Pavilhão 5
...
```

Como você pode ver foi fácil extrair os dados deste site, eles já vieram estruturados de maneira organizada no código javascript. Porém nem sempre é fácil assim - hoje em dia é cada vez mais comum sites dinâmicos com código javascript cada vez mais confuso e obscuro. Entra então a outra alternativa para scraping deste tipo de site: o `selenium` - Selenium é uma lib que permite controlar um navegador através do python, como o chrome ou o firefox - Usando ele é possível executar javascript. Porém é bem menos eficiente porque você está executando um browser inteiro.

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado! eu havia visto o selenium, mas pensava que com o bs4 seria melhor,vou testar aqui ! valeu !